# use glob module to get certain files with python?

Tags: python-3.x

The following is a piece of the code:

```
files = glob.iglob(studentDir + '/**/*.py',recursive=True)
for file in files:
    shutil.copy(file, newDir)
```

The thing is: I plan to get all the files with extension .py and also all the files whose names contain "write". Is there anything I can do to change my code? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that recursive option, you could use :

```
patterns = ['/**/*write*','/**/*.py']
for p in patterns:
    files = glob.iglob(studentDir + p, recursive=True)
    for file in files:
        shutil.copy(file, newDir)
```

If the wanted files are in the same directory you could simply use :

```
certainfiles = [glob.glob(e) for e in ['*.py', '*write*']]
for file in certainfiles:
    shutil.copy(file, newDir)
```

Comment: patterns = ['/**/*.txt','/**/*.py']
        for p in patterns:
            if isCS1:
               files = glob.iglob(studentDir + p, recursive=True)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of `pathlib` which has been available from version 3.4. It makes many things considerably easier.

- In this case '**' stands for 'descend the entire folder'.
- '*.py' has its usual meaning.
- `path` is an object but you can recover its string representation using the `str` function to get just the file name.
- When you want the entire *path* name, use `path.absolute` and get the `str` of that.

Don't worry, you'll get used to it. :) If you look at the other goodies in pathlib you'll see it's worth it.

```
from pathlib import Path
studentDir = <something>
newDir = <something else>
for path in Path(studentDir).glob('**/*.py'):
    if 'write' in str(path):
        shutil.copy(str(path.absolute()), newDir)
```